# ImageButton ID fetch in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

There are some Image buttons in my Page.In database, I am storing which buttons to display which image. But while displaying in the page I am not able to display. No Error is showing but the images are not displayed.
 The code is:`

```
DataSet dsSeat = new DataSet();
dsSeat=objSeat.SeatView();
for (int i = 0; i < dsSeat.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
ImageButton Button1 = new ImageButton();
Button1.ID = dsSeat.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Image"].ToString();
Button1.ImageUrl = "~/App_Images/1.png";
}
```

In some Event, I can fetch the ID using

```
ImageButton CurrentButton = (ImageButton)sender;
string buttonId = CurrentButton.ID;
CurrentButton.ImageUrl = "~/App_Images/1.png";
```

But as i am using it in a method not in event, How to do it?

Comment: have u taken any repeater or gridview???fror multiple buttons?

Comment: no i have simply taken in the page @Killer R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just creating the `ImageButton` objects without actually inserting them on the page. Choose some container, like the `Panel1` in the example below, and insert your buttons to its `Controls` collection:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dsSeat.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    ImageButton Button1 = new ImageButton();
    Button1.ID = dsSeat.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Image"].ToString();
    Button1.ImageUrl = "~/App_Images/1.png";

    Panel1.Controls.Add(Button1);
}
```

Of course it might be more complicated logic instead of simple inserting into `Panel` - this depends on your requirements.

**Update.** From comments it seems that your problem is elsewhere. If you need to set an image on the control that is already on the page like this:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="A1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Images/0.png" />
```

just call it with its id in code behind:

```
A1.ImageUrl = "~/App_Images/1.png";
```

If you are receiving ID from DB, then you can use `FindControl` on the button's immediate container (say `Panel1`):

```
for (int i = 0; i < dsSeat.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    ImageButton Button1 = Panel1.FindControl(dsSeat.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Image"].ToString());
    Button1.ImageUrl = "~/App_Images/1.png";
}
```

Please note that this is just a guess, it is not clear from your question what the exact problem is.

Comment: I have taken the control.  <asp:ImageButton ID="A1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Images/0.png" />  Now just want to change Image by taking the value from database

Comment: @Shovan, this is something very different from your original question. Please provide more details on your problem, otherwise it is impossible to help you

Comment: @Shovan, see update, i've tried to guess what your problem might be

Comment: I have taken some imagebutton controls having some images. I want to display images in that controls according to the data retrieved from database. how to solve it.